# Although there is no logical error in the class, the program does not see class2 when trying to create an object in the Main method. can u help me?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Everything was going perfectly until the Main method. I inherited the fields and properties of class1 to class2. There was no problem so far, the compiler did not give any errors. Then, when I went to the main method and wanted to create an object from class2, I saw that the program did not see class2. visual studio 2022 was giving an error. I asked ChatGPT, he wrote relatively the same code as me, and while his code was working smoothly, mine was giving errors. However, there is no error in my code. I'm really confused, I didn't understand anything. It would be great if you could help. This problem is very interesting. I hope you can help me. Have a nice day :)
Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp96
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public class class1
        {
            private string kullaniciAdi; //kullaniciAdi : username
            private string sifre;  //sifre : password

            public string KullaniciAdi
            {
                get
                {
                    return kullaniciAdi;
                }

                set
                {
                    kullaniciAdi = value;
                }
            }

            public string Sifre
            {
                get
                {
                    return sifre;
                }

                set
                {
                    sifre = value;
                }
            }

            public class1()
            {
              
            }

            public class class2 : class1
            {

            }
            
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            class2 c = new class2();
        }
    }
}
```

My main goal was to combine encapsulation and inheritance so that I could better understand these two principles. But unfortunately my code gave an error. I explained it in detail above.

Comment: "Everything was going perfectly until the Main method." Good quote for a t-shirt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created nested classes here. That is usually not the best solution, so I would move `class2` outside of `class1`. However, if you need to keep it in there, you need to tell the compiler the class is nested, for example:

```
class1.class2 c = new class1.class2();
```